# MessageStore backed QueueChannel with Spring Integration+ Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

The Spring Integration [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle) refers to using a MessageStore implementation to provide persistence to a QueueChannel.

It's mentioned many times but all examples are using XML config, i.e

```
<int:channel id="dbBackedChannel">
    <int:queue message-store="channelStore"/>
</int:channel>

<bean id="channelStore" class="o.s.i.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider" ref="queryProvider"/>
</bean>
```

But the implementation of [QueueChannel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/api/org/springframework/integration/channel/QueueChannel.html) has no methods for setting the MessageStore

So how could I create a QueueChannel with a MessageStore without using XML configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse engineered what the XML config did, and this is the answer.

You have a wrap the MessageStore in a [MessageGroupQueue](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/store/MessageGroupQueue.html)

So it would look something like this

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel messageStoreBackedChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel(
        new MessageGroupQueue(<<MessageStoreImplementation>>, "Group ID")
    );
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to store the actual messages, but only a sequence number for me unfortunately. I'll dive in the integration docs, and post another comment if someone else has the same problem ;)