# Spring integration messagestore backed queue + java config

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am currently part of a project where we are using Spring integration. And to make the queuechannel persistent we are planning to use jdbcmessagestore. But not able to find any java config or any method as part of queuechannel to add messagestore as shown in xml config.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538885/messagestore-backed-queuechannel-with-spring-integration-java-config?rq=1

Comment: Yes have seen this one but does not operate or store the message completely was searching if there is any other mechanism